# Scraping American data from Canada with python

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm scraping several sites for e-commerce data  with scrapy or just lxml/requests
I want American prices but the sites recognize me as Canadian and give me Canadian prices.

Is there a way to scrape American versions of sites with python?

Comment: Could you use a VPN with a US server?

Comment: Does the site have currency options? If so, can't you choose that option and then scrape?

Comment: Really, it depends on the site. For some sites, the only way is to get an IP in that country.

Comment: I'm using a VPN, thank you

Comment: It might be simpler to just implement a spider pipeline that converts Canadian prices to American prices.